# Repetition in making dataframes using a for loop in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

trying to work with this dataframe **x** in python -

[image: data-example]

along with this, i have a list of column names of this dataframe {except column **Cust_ID**}

> columns = [2021_W46, .... , 2022_W9]

Using this, I'm filtering the dataframe column-wise such as to get 3 columns in each dataframe which will be **"Cust_id", "2022_W[i]", "2022_W[i+1]"**

Since the data is starting from 2022_W46, I need a list of 15 dataframes.

To make these 15 dataframes into a list, I'm using the following code

```
tables =[]
for no, name in enumerate(cols):
    print(no)
    print(name)
    if no >= 1:
        x1 = x.iloc[:,[0,no,no+1]]
    tables.append(x1)
```

Using this loop, a list of 16 dataframes is created.

Now the error is that there should be a list of 15 dataframes since the slicing should start from 2021_W47 since there is no pre-existing week from 2021_W46.

Pin-pointing on the error, the dataframe containing **"Cust_ID", "2022_W8", "2022_W9"** has occurred twice in the list.

Can anybody help me understand why exactly could this be happening?

Comment: I could be wrong but based on your description, i think it shall be `x1 = x.iloc[:,no-1:no]` to get the 15 dfs with adjacent columns. If it does not help, please provide the df or df.to_dict() so I can test out with the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
tables =[]
cols = df.columns[1:]
for no, name in enumerate(cols):
    print(name)
    if no >= 1:
        x1 = df.iloc[:,[0,no,no+1]]
        tables.append(x1)
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]